# Web App for clearing files

Tags: php, linux, bash, scripting, automation

In my environment at work, which is primarily RHEL 6/7, we have a file system that keeps filling up with log files, that are not incredibly important, so we `cat /dev/null > $file` in that specific directory.

My limitations are not bound by root as our account has that level of access, and our account is on every server.  I cannot perform `cron` jobs, due to security issues, and the only platform I know of in-house is something that requires an agent, but were talking hundreds/thousands of servers... not happening.

My team has developed a web application in PHP that runs certain things for us to make our lives easier.  My question is: in this situation/environment I'm in, what would be the best way to go about this?  I'm thinking of creating a simple form that has the server inputted (maybe multiple ones delimited) and then, when submitted, it runs a few `shell_exec` commands by going to the server(s) and zero'ing out those files.

A good note would be: the location is static, and the files in question static.  Thank you in advance for you input!

Answer (score 1):

Your server admin(s) should correctly configure logrotated.  Why on earth cron jobs are a "security" concern when others are given root access to the box I have no idea...

Comment: thanks, ivanivan.  i couldn't speak towards why they think it is a "security" issue, or that's just the way they announced when someone probably screwed something up, and that 'something' was in the form of a cron job.  I'll look into logrotate, thanks!